# Simple PFQuery takes too long

Tags: performance, parse-platform, local-database, local-datastore

I have a simple class called TaskType:

```
@interface TaskType : PFObject <PFSubclassing>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFObject *user;

@end
```

Then I have a simple query for task types:

```
PFQuery *taskTypesQuery = [TaskType query];
[taskTypesQuery fromLocalDatastore];
[taskTypesQuery whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

NSLog(@"start fetching task types");
[taskTypesQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"task types fetched: %d", [objects count]);
}];
```

And here is the log output:

```
2015-07-30 13:44:01.548 start fetching task types
2015-07-30 13:44:02.949 task types fetched: 20
```

Why it takes 1400ms to query 20 items from LOCAL DATASTORE!?

Testing on iPod Touch 5. On my iPhone 6 it takes about 500-600ms for the same query, but it is still too much! Is it a kind of a bug or am I doing something wrong? How can I minimise the query time?

P.S.: The same query on my iPod 5 WITHOUT this "fromLocalDatastore" thing shows me the following:

```
2015-07-30 13:47:51.126 start fetching task types
2015-07-30 13:47:51.455 task types fetched: 20
```

How is it possible that fetching from remote takes 3-4 times less time than the same fetch from local datastore?...

Comment: Is the data stored into the local datastore before this query? Is it possible it has to look in local datastore, then fetch remotely, fill in the local datastore, and then return the results?

Comment: Hmm.... actually, strange thing happens. I disabled WiFi and the same request became really fast - something about 200 or 300 ms. But how is it possible? Looks like it asks for updates from remote before fetching. Is it possible to just fetch from local? Thanks!

Comment: Another update. Today I've tested it with airplane mode again. And result is the same as in the beginning - 1200ms for simple request.

Comment: Which version of the Parse SDK are you using?

Comment: From CocoaPods:
Using Parse (1.7.5.3)
Using ParseUI (1.1.4)